# How to change button image when hovering

Tags: javascript, android, button

I have an analog remote that has a `DPAD` functionality. When I press it, the button in my app to which it is over will darken, and when I push select that button is selected.

Is there a way I can detect which button is being hovered over programmatically? And no, `onHover()` doesn't work in this instance.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: you want button press and finger left after button pressed ?

Comment: No just for the `BackgroundImageResource` to change when my remote is hovering over it.

Comment: is that button do some operation when u click on it

Comment: When I push `LEFT` on my DPAD for example I guess it is the equivalent of pushing `Tab` on a computer. Same function I need to detect.